# monix: Task.executeWithFork prevents execution?

Tags: scala, monix

I can't figure out why adding `executeWithFork` prevents task from running in the following example:

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import monix.execution.schedulers.SchedulerService
import monix.reactive.subjects.ConcurrentSubject

object Sandbox {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val scheduler: SchedulerService =
      monix.execution.Scheduler(java.util.concurrent.Executors.newCachedThreadPool())

    val input = ConcurrentSubject.publish[String]

    // prints nothing
    input.foreachL(println).executeWithFork.runAsync
    // this works:
    // input.foreachL(println).runAsync

    input.onNext("one")
    input.onNext("two")

    scheduler.shutdown()
    scheduler.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is a result of two facts:

1. using `executeWithFork` introduce a bit of additional latency for thread switch
2. you use `ConcurrentSubject.publish` (as opposed to `replay` for example). If you open the docs for [`PublishSubject`](https://monix.io/api/2.3/monix/reactive/subjects/PublishSubject.html) you may see that

> A `PublishSubject` emits to a subscriber only those items that are emitted by the source subsequent to the time of the subscription.

In other words you have a race condition between the main thread that publishes the `"one"` and `"two"` and the forked thread that has to subscribe to the `input` to get the data. Results depends on which thread wins the race: all the data published before the subscription is lost. One my hardware I almost always see `"two"` and very occasionally even see `"one"`, your results might vary.

The simplest way to test this is to add `Thread.sleep(100)` before the first `input.onNext` and you should see both events printed every time. You may also try to push more events than just 2 to see that not everything is lost.